# Choosing Q point for MOSFET amplifier

Tags: mosfet

[image]

These are some lecture notes for MOSFET amplifier.
Why has he chosen Q point using Vd?
Shouldn't Vds = 1/2(Vdd + Vgs - Vt) ?

Comment: You didn't include the voltage across the source resistor. Apart from that your expression is the same as the one above.

Comment: For choosing a Q point between Vds(sat) and Vcc, that is Vds = 1/2(Vdd + Vgs - Vt) ?

Comment: Your expression does not include the voltage across Rs. This can be considered to be DC because of the capacitor across it. So the effective Vdd is Vdd - Vs.